# Incorrect number of method arguments when using F# interactive in Xamarin Studio

Tags: dll, f#, mono, xamarin-studio, f#-interactive

I have a small library using RabbitMQ from F# which works fine using Visual Studio, both compiled and in F# interactive.

When I try to load it in the latest (6.1) Xamarin Studio, the library compiles fine but attempt to load its source files in F# interactive fails complaining about incorrect number of arguments for certain methods.

For example, RabbitMQ IModel.ExchangeDeclare has 3 overloads that have 2, 3, and 5 arguments (I can verify it using Xamarin Assembly Browser). The library is using an overload with 5 arguments. F# Interactive prints an error stating that there is no overload with 5 arguments so I am unable to execute RabbitMQ API methods interactively. Howevever the project compiles fine. I believe this error has nothing to do with RabbitMQ, but why F# Interactive gets confused?

Comment: At least post a simple example - but my guess is you are referencing different DLLs

Comment: As I wrote above, the ExhangeDeclare call with 5 arguments fail, e.g. channel.ExchangeDeclare(queueExchange.ExchangeName, exchangeName, queueExchange.Durable, false, queueExchange.Arguments).
I will search for other RabbitMQ.dlls. So far this looks strange.

Comment: Yes you were right: this is what is referenced:
Referenced '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.0/lib/mono/4.5/RabbitMQ.Client.dll' (file may be locked by F# Interactive process)

The question is now: how should I overwrite this? I have #I statement that refers to a correct path.

Comment: My guess is that the `#r` directives in the fsi file aren't matching the references in your project - check that they all match

Comment: Yes, you are right. F# Interactive works differently in VS and Xamarin IDE, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As it was suggested in comments, it must be different DLLs; and it was. The problem is that F# Interactive used by Visual Studio in Windows uses different logic comparing how it's handled by FSI in Xamarin/Mono.

Visual Studio in Windows can be controlled by `#I directive`, so it's not recommended to specify relative path in `#r directive` (more about it here: [Avoid using relative paths in #r directives](https://sergeytihon.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/avoid-using-relative-paths-in-r-directives/)), but Xamarin/Mono requires path specification right in #r directive to load the right DLL.